# Building Tizen Native Project and Packaging by CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, packaging, tizen, building, tizen-native-app

I use Command Line Interface (Tizen SDK 2.3) to build and create tpk packages for my tizen native project.

It may sound strange but I had a serious problem while building and packing. Suddenly all of my data were wiped out. I thought that it might happen because of virus or hardware issue and then I reinstalled my operating system to a new hard drive and tried to build and pack my project by CLI and unfortunately everything was wiped out again. Even bash in home directory. While building and packing, I was checking cpu and memory usage of processes, then I realized that top process was "rm" and it was using cpu around %95 and removing everything.

Any idea to solve this problem? Or anyone had some similar issue with Command Line Interface in Tizen SDK 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay in reply. If you are still facing this issue it will be helpful if you tell me which sdk version you are using, I can tell exactly what's happening and how to avoid it. In mean time, here is my analysis which might help.

I am using tizen sdk 2.3 rev2 and though I was not able to reproduce this issue with it, I have analysed generated makefiles for the project during CLI build and found that there is one situation where this can happen, which requires following conditions to be true.

- CLI build is using llvm compiler.
- 'SA_REPORT_PATH' environment variable is not defined.
- During build, make tries to build 'sa' or 'clean' target.

I am not facing this issue because CLI builds tools in my sdk defines 'SA_REPORT_PATH' environment variable to 'ProjectFolder/SA_Report' folder before building project.

To see if this is happening in your case, you can rename 'rm' to some thing else for testing and copy 'echo' as 'rm' using following command or similar.

```
> sudo mv /bin/rm /bin/rm_
> sudo cp /bin/echo /bin/rm
```

Then try to build your project using CLI, if you get line something like

```
-rf src/basic_ui.c.ast src/basic_ui.c.fn     /bin /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home ......
```

Then this might be causing deletion of all files, you can avoid this by defining 'SA_REPORT_PATH' to some default value before using any CLI tool.

```
> export SA_REPORT_PATH=<absolute path to some empty directory>
```